# Two dimensional array in python

Tags: python, win32com

I need to read values from excel worksheet into 2d array.can anyone tell me how to do this using pythonwin32com.

Comment: Show what you have tried as it is difficult to know which aspect of this task you are having problem with, as you can see from answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multi dimensional arrays or objects, your choice :)

`arr = []; arr.append([1,2]); print arr;`

would output

`[[1,2]]`

Comment: thank you. but i would like to know how to read my entire worksheet into array

Comment: Can you export the excel doc as a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to Excel cells like this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Full_path_to_your_excel_file")
sheet = wb.ActiveSheet

print sheet.Range('A1:C1')
```

But it is unclear for me what you want to put into 2d array.